Calculate median of a pipelines' network using MILP in a smarter way
I want to calculate the median value of a network of pipelines. I am currently using pulp to calculate the solution.
Without going into too many details, here's my current dumb solution:
Variables:
# Distance variable for each pipeline
D_p = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('D_p', pipelines, lowBound=0)

# Median Travel Distance | D_median
D_median = pulp.LpVariable('D_median', lowBound=0)

# Binary Variables for Median Constraints
z_p = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('z_p', pipelines, cat='Binary')  # z_p = 1 if D_p <= D_median
w_p = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('w_p', pipelines, cat='Binary')  # w_p = 1 if D_p >= D_median

pipelines is simply a list of pipelines of varying lengths for which I want to find the median.
Constraints for the above variables:
# M is a large constant that's bigger than any possible pipeline distance

# Median Constraints:
# z_p = 1 if D_p[p] ≤ D_median  => D_p[p] - D_median ≤ M*(1 - z_p)
# w_p = 1 if D_p[p] ≥ D_median  => D_median - D_p[p] ≤ M*(1 - w_p)

for p in pipelines:
    prob += D_p[p] - D_median <= M * (1 - z_p[p]), f"Less_Or_Equal_{p[2]}"
    prob += D_median - D_p[p] <= M * (1 - w_p[p]), f"Greater_Or_Equal_{p[2]}"

# At least half of the pipelines must be ≤ D_median and at least half ≥ D_median
half = (num_pipelines + 1) // 2
prob += pulp.lpSum(z_p[p] for p in pipelines) >= half, "Half_Less_Or_Equal"
prob += pulp.lpSum(w_p[p] for p in pipelines) >= half, "Half_Greater_Or_Equal"

This solution is incredibly slow. I am absolutely sure there's a smarter way to calculate the median.
I'd appreciate some guidance and pointers as I am lost.

Related: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/11488/how-to-set-up-a-constraint-that-represents-a-median

Could you explicit the constraints for the pipeline distances?

@Kuifje can you explain what you mean by that?

@RobPratt thanks for the link. I can see that you have answered the question and the solution is similar to mine. Am I understanding it correctly?

it may be possible to improve the formulation if you share the whole model. Maybe the other constraints "hide" some information on the median that can be used. For example, are the pipeline distances bounded?
